# Is there any FAST way to do the following in python for time series data?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, date, time-series, grouping

I have a time series dataset as show below

```
id         date          sales
0          2016-01-01    11.0
1          2016-01-02    12.0
2          2016-01-03    3.0
3          2016-01-08    3.1
4          2016-01-09    11.0
5          2016-01-10    34.2
6          2016-01-15    34.2
7          2016-01-16    34.2
8          2016-01-18    11.0
```

Questions:

1. Is there any way to find the frequency of the date column (given that it is not continous). I would prefer to find the frequency based on the most occuring frequency. (i.e. here it is 'daily'). Please note that `.inferred_freq` will give me `None` as the frequency.
2. Suppose I have another dataset that contains the missing dates in the first dataset as shown below:

```
id         date        
0          2016-01-04   
1          2016-01-05    
2          2016-01-06   
3          2016-01-07   
4          2016-01-11   
5          2016-01-12    
6          2016-01-13    
7          2016-01-14
```

Here, I need to group the dates in the first dataset based on the condition that if the next missing date is available in the second dataframe in the **FASTEST way possible**. So, my first dataset should look like this:

```
id         date          sales    Group_id
0          2016-01-01    11.0     1 
1          2016-01-02    12.0     1
2          2016-01-03    3.0      1
3          2016-01-08    3.1      2
4          2016-01-09    11.0     2
5          2016-01-10    34.2     2
6          2016-01-15    34.2     3
7          2016-01-16    34.2     3
8          2016-01-18    11.0     3
```

3. Is there any **FAST** way (keeping in mind that the dataframe may contains millions of rows) to remove the rows that are not repeating based on a column value (say, sales). Here, the non-repeating rows that I **want to remove** based on the column **sales** will be :

```
1          2016-01-02    12.0
2          2016-01-03    3.0
3          2016-01-08    3.1
```

because the sales column has unique values for these three rows.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, Q1 and Q2 are the same: use `diff` to check whether the difference is 1 day, and then use `cumsum`:

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
df["group"] = (df["date"].diff()>pd.Timedelta(days=1)).cumsum()+1
print (df)

   id       date  sales  group
0   0 2016-01-01   11.0      1
1   1 2016-01-02   12.0      1
2   2 2016-01-03    3.0      1
3   3 2016-01-08    3.1      2
4   4 2016-01-09   14.0      2
5   5 2016-01-10   34.2      2
6   6 2016-01-15   34.2      3
7   7 2016-01-16   34.2      3
8   8 2016-01-17   14.0      3
9   9 2016-01-18   11.0      3
```

Use `drop_duplicates` with `keep=False` for the unique sales values:

```
print (df.drop_duplicates("sales", keep=False))
   id       date  sales  group
1   1 2016-01-02   12.0      1
2   2 2016-01-03    3.0      1
3   3 2016-01-08    3.1      2
```

Or `duplicated` to get results without unique:

```
print (df[df.duplicated("sales", keep=False)])
   id       date  sales  group
0   0 2016-01-01   11.0      1
4   4 2016-01-09   14.0      2
5   5 2016-01-10   34.2      2
6   6 2016-01-15   34.2      3
7   7 2016-01-16   34.2      3
8   8 2016-01-17   14.0      3
9   9 2016-01-18   11.0      3
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but your answer for Q2 is not exactly what I wanted. Suppose there is a date missing but it is not there in the second dataframe, I dont want to group the dates succeeding the missing date as seperate, but as same group as the previous date group.That is why I specifically mentioned based on the condition that if the next missing date is available in the second dataframe. Thanks for other answers though. I appreciate it.. Please answer for this.

Comment: You should always include sample with all expected cases.

Comment: Alright, I have edited the dataframe and the 2nd question.

Comment: I think the core of the problem is your 2nd df doesn't actually serve as a reference. Containing empty dates are not really helpful for a lookup. What people normally expect is a reference df with start to end period of each group.